# POST request returns 404 (Not Found); Next-authentication/Next.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, next.js

My error is coming from the frontend:

`Login.js:44 POST http://localhost:8016/ 404 (Not Found)`

This is my `Login.js` component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Router from 'next/router'
import { login } from 'next-authentication'

import { Button, Form, Grid, Header, Message, Segment } from 'semantic-ui-react'
// import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      isLoggedIn: false,
      username: '',
      password: ''
    }

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.handleIsLoggedInClick = this.handleIsLoggedInClick.bind(this)
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({})
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    var { name, value } = event.target
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    })
  }

  handleIsLoggedInClick() {
    var { isLoggedIn } = this.state
    !isLoggedIn ? this.setState({ isLoggedIn: true }) : this.setState({ isLoggedIn: false })
  }

  async handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    const { username, password } = this.state

    try {
      const response = await window.fetch('http://localhost:8016/', {
        method: 'post',
        body: JSON.stringify({ username, password }),
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
      })

      if (response.ok) {
        const { token } = await response.json()
        const loginOptions = {
          token,
          cookieOptions: { expires: 1 },
          callback: () => Router.push('/users')
        }
        login(loginOptions)
      } else {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log('Login failed.')
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Implementation or Network error.')
    }
  }

  render() {
    var { username, password, isLoggedIn } = this.state
    return (
      <div className='login-form'>
        <style>
          {`
      body > div,
      body > div > div,
      body > div > div > div.login-form {
        height: 100%;
      }
    `}
        </style>
        <Grid textAlign='center' style={{ height: '100%' }} verticalAlign='middle'>
          <Grid.Column style={{ maxWidth: 450 }}>
            <Header as='h2' color='teal' textAlign='center'>
              {isLoggedIn ? `Register for an account` : ` Log-in to your account`}
            </Header>
            <Form size='large' onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
              <Segment stacked>
                <Form.Input
                  fluid
                  icon='user'
                  iconPosition='left'
                  placeholder='E-mail address'
                  name='username'
                  value={username}
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                />

                <Form.Input
                  fluid
                  icon='lock'
                  iconPosition='left'
                  placeholder='Password'
                  name='password'
                  value={password}
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
                <Button color='teal' fluid size='large'>
                  {isLoggedIn ? `Register` : `Log-in`}
                </Button>
              </Segment>
            </Form>
            {!isLoggedIn
              ? <Message>
                New to us?
                <a onClick={this.handleIsLoggedInClick} href='#'> Register!</a>
              </Message>
              : <Message>
                <a onClick={this.handleIsLoggedInClick} href='#'>Back to Login</a>
              </Message>
            }
          </Grid.Column>
        </Grid>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Login
```

I've checked via `MongoCompass` for the users and I don't see anything:

[image]

This is my express app:

```
/* eslint-disable no-console */
/* eslint-disable no-shadow */
var express = require('express')
var next = require('next')
var session = require('express-session')
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session)
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var cors = require('cors')
// var morgan = require('morgan');
var HttpStatus = require('http-status-codes')

var PORT = process.env.PORT || 8016
var dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
var NextApp = next({ dev })
var handle = NextApp.getRequestHandler()

var mongoose = require('mongoose')

var db = `mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/hillfinder`

function errorHandler (err, req, res, next) {
  // Set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {}

  // Log error
  console.error(err.stack)

  // Render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500)

  // Default error message by HTTP code
  res.render('error', {
    title: HttpStatus.getStatusText(err.status),
    message: HttpStatus.getStatusText(err.status)
  })
}

const users = require('./routes')

NextApp.prepare()
  .then(() => {
    const app = express()
    mongoose.connect(db)
    mongoose.Promise = global.Promise

    mongoose.connection
      .on('connected', () => {
        console.log(`Mongoose connection open on ${db}`)
      })
      .on('error', err => {
        console.log(`Connection error: ${err.message}`)
      })

    app.use(bodyParser.json())
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
    // app.use(morgan('combined'));

    app.use(cookieParser())
    app.use(
      session({
        secret: 'very secret 12345',
        resave: true,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection })
      })
    )
    app.use(cors())

    // eslint-disable-next-line global-require
    app.use('/', users)

    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
      return handle(req, res)
    })

    // eslint-disable-next-line func-names
    app.use(errorHandler, function (error, req, res, next) {
      res.json({ message: error.message })
    })

    app.listen(PORT, err => {
      if (err) throw err
      console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${PORT}`)
    })
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err)
  })
```

This is the index file which manages all my routes `server/routes/index.js`

```
var router = require('express').Router();

router.use('/users', require('./users'));

module.exports = router;
```

This is my users route `server/routes/users`

```
var router = require('express').Router()
var UserModel = require('../../models/UserModel')

router
  .route('/')
  .get(function (req, res) {
    UserModel.find({}, (err, users) => {
      if (err) res.status(500).send(err)
      res.json(users)
    })
  })
  .post((req, res) => {
    UserModel.create({
      username: req.email,
      password: req.password
    }, (err, user) => {
      if (err) res.status(500).send(err)
      res.json(user)
    })
  })
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Won't this part ```var router = require('express').Router();

router.use('/users', require('./users'));

module.exports = router;``` expect you to send yout login request to `/users` and not the domain root ?

Comment: @Nazim how to send it